# Create a new column from two tables based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nested-lists

medicament has a list of id_questions_similar and each of those questions has some specialty_id in the other table(active_questions).I need to gather up all specialty_id matching the id_questions and create a new list containing all the specialty id's for the corresponding question id's and place in the new column in the table medicament_similar

[image: a simple]

```
data1 = {'id_questions': [1,2,3],
        'speciality_id': [[77, 66],[111, 122,133],[1245]]

        }

active_questions = pd.DataFrame(data1)
active_questions

data2 = {'id_medicament': [1, 2,3],
        'id_questions_similar': [[1, 2],[1,3], [3]]
        }

medicament_similar = pd.DataFrame(data2)

medicament_similar
```

I created this sample to better explain the problem (I have two tables with more than 10000 lines)
Im looking to get this result (that I did manually) :

[image: final_result that Im looking for]

I tried this but no result:

```
def get_specialities(data1, data2):

    for i in data1['speciality_id']:

        for l in data1['id_questions']:

            for k in range(len(data2['id_questions_similar'])):

                drug_speciality = []

                if k == l :

                    drug_speciality.append(data1['speciality_id'])
                    return drug_speciality

print(get_specialities(data_1, data_2))
```

Comment: Please provide the output, errors, stack trace. Thanks

Comment: Added a more optimal version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this. Probably can do everything on pandas and more optimally..?
data 1['id_questions'] is looking for an occurrence in data 2['id_questions_similar'][i].
Based on these occurrences, indexes are calculated and values from 'questions['speciality_id']' are obtained.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'id_questions': [1, 2, 3],
        'speciality_id': [[77, 66], [111, 122, 133], [1245]]
        }

active_questions = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'id_medicament': [1, 2, 3],
        'id_questions_similar': [[1, 2], [1, 3], [3]]
        }

questions = pd.DataFrame(data2)

even_numbers = list(range(len(data2['id_questions_similar'])))

for i in range (0, len(data2['id_questions_similar'])):
        qqq = list(filter(lambda aaa: aaa in data1['id_questions'], data2['id_questions_similar'][i]))
        print(qqq)
        index_ = []
        count_ = len(qqq)
        for k in range(0, count_):
            ind = data1['id_questions'].index(qqq[k])#index
            if count_ == 1:
                    even_numbers[i] = data1['speciality_id'][ind]
                    continue
            index_.append(data1['speciality_id'][ind])#values
        if count_ > 1:
                even_numbers[i] = index_

questions['speciality_id'] = even_numbers
print(questions)
```

Below I made a more optimal version.

```
import more_itertools as mit
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'id_questions': [1, 2, 3],
        'speciality_id': [[77, 66], [111, 122, 133], [1245]]
        }

active_questions = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'id_medicament': [1, 2, 3],
        'id_questions_similar': [[1, 2], [1, 3], [3]]
        }

questions = pd.DataFrame(data2)

iterable = active_questions['id_questions']
speciality = []
for i in questions['id_questions_similar']:
    index = list(mit.locate(iterable, lambda x: x in i))
    if len(index) > 1:
        speciality.append(list(active_questions.iloc[index, 1]))
    else:
        speciality.append(active_questions.iloc[index[0], 1])


questions['speciality_id'] = speciality
print(questions)
```